# Error "ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to connect to localhost:1443 - Could not connect (sequence)" using sequelize-automate

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, tedious

I'm getting a connection error when trying to automatically create the db table models using sequelize-automate.

However, the connection I'm using for sequelize is working but it's in a different format and I'm not sure if sequelize-automate allows me to use the same format.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const util = require('util');
const dbSequelize = require('../public/dbconfigSequelize.json');

let databaseUrl = util.format(
  dbSequelize.server,
  dbSequelize.username,
  dbSequelize.password,
  dbSequelize.host,
  dbSequelize.database
)

function getConnection() {
  console.log('creating a new connection');
  return new Sequelize(databaseUrl, {
    pool: {
      max: 1
    },
    logging: console.log
  });
}

function checkAuthenticate() {
  sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
}

const sequelize = getConnection();
checkAuthenticate();

module.exports = sequelize;
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "generate-sequelize-models": "sequelize-automate -c sequelize-automate.config.json"
  }
```

sequelize-automate.config.json

```
{
  "dbOptions": {
    "database": "mydbname",
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "logging": false
  },
  "options": {
    "type": "js",
    "dir": "./server/models"
  }
}
```

The error:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp> npm run generate-sequelize-models

> myelectronapp@0.1.0 generate-sequelize-models C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp
> sequelize-automate -c sequelize-automate.config.json

Database options: {"database":"mydbname","username":"myusername","password":"****","dialect":"mssql","host":"localhost","port":3306,"logging":false}
Automate options: {"type":"js","camelCase":false,"dir":"./server/models","emptyDir":false}
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Failed to connect to localhost:3306 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:134:17
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:3306 - Could not connect (sequence)
      at ConnectionError (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1288:56)
      at C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1114:21
      at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:87:14)
      at Socket.onError (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:100:12)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:3306 - Could not connect (sequence)',
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  },
  original: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:3306 - Could not connect (sequence)
      at ConnectionError (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1288:56)
      at C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1114:21
      at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:87:14)
      at Socket.onError (C:\Users\username\Documents\myelectronapp\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:100:12)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:3306 - Could not connect (sequence)',
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, this is not from sequelize-automate but quite likely your issue is not particular to that anyway, otherwise it would be well documented by others

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2133

can't help but notice the error in the title is not the same as the error in your trace above either... why is it using default port for mySQL instead of mssql

Comment: Thank you! Turning on the SQL Server Browser worked for me. Now I'm getting another error but that's db related.

Comment: Excellent glad it got you moving! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error appeared because I had wrong `dialect`: `mssql` instead of `mysql`.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('Users', 'admin', 'pswd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3307,
    dialect: 'mssql'
});
```

Updating the `dialect` to `mysql` fixed it.